# JOptionPane with a JTextArea instead of a text field?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea, joptionpane

I need to grab multiple lines of input from a popup JOptionPane (or some other popup, but most of my searches direct me there, which is where I get stuck..). I am stuck at using

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, new JTextArea(20,20));
```

but I want just the 20x20 area to be read to a String and no text field shown.
I figure there must be some way to do this, but the other types of dialog only seem to return an int... It doesn't have to be a JOptionPane, as long as it is a separate popup from my main GUI that can read a string back in to be read.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keep a reference to the `JTextArea` before passing to the `JOptionPane`, the `JOptionPane` will tell you what the user did (how they closed the dialog) and depending on the result, you might want to do different things

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(20, 20);
switch (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, new JScrollPane(ta))) {
    case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
        System.out.println(ta.getText());
        break;
}
```

See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, ta)` I suspect that would best be `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, new JScrollPane(ta))`.  To my eye, a text area added to a GUI without a scroll pane in between just ..looks strange.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Agreed, without the `JScrollPane`, the `JTextArea` would be able to grow as it required more space

Comment: Thanks guys! Only thing I see is I'm getting a "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String" on the line
    case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:

Comment: That looks pretty good, just a matter of making it actually do work now. GUIs are definitely not my thing.